# Augmentation Ideal of Group Ring of Free Group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $RG$ be a group ring, where $R$ is a commutative ring. Let $I=\ker\epsilon$ be the augmentation ideal.

It is known that any element $\alpha\in I$ can be written in the form $$\alpha=\sum_{g\in G}a_g(g-1),$$ where $a_g\in R$.

Suppose further that $G$ is a free group with generators $g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n$. With this extra information, how can we improve on the previous result?

For example is it true that $\alpha$ can be written in the form $$\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^n\left( a_g(g_i-1)+b_g(g_i^{-1}-1)\right)?$$

Thanks.

Comment: It seems the element $g_1^2 - g_1 \in I$ is not of the required form.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewed as an $R$-module, the ideal $I$ is free, and a basis is given by $\mathcal{B} = \{ g-1 \ | \ g\in G\}$ (proof below).  Therefore, if $G$ is any group (including free groups), it is not possible to "improve" on this basis in any sense that I can think of.

---

*Proof that $\mathcal{B} = \{ g-1 \ | \ g\in G\}$ is a basis of $I$ as an $R$-module.*

To see that $\mathcal{B}$ generates $I$, let $x=\sum_g b_g g \in I$.  Since $x\in I$, we have that $b_1 = -\sum_{g\neq 1} b_g$.  Therefore $$ x = \sum_{g\neq 1} b_g(g-1).$$
Thus $\mathcal{B}$ generates $I$.

To see that the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ are linearly independent, assume that $$ \sum_{g\neq 1} a_g(g-1) =0. $$  Written in the basis $\{g \ | \ g\in G\}$ of $RG$, this element is $$(-\sum_{g\neq 1}a_g) 1 + \sum_{g\neq 1}a_g g.$$ Thus, $a_g=0$ for all $g\in G \setminus \{1\}$.

Therefore, $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of the $R$-module $I$.